# Is the fundamental theorem of calculus valid for functions in $W^{1,1}(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

We know that it is **not** true that  "$f:[a,b]\subseteq\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ differentiable a.e. implies that
$$ f(x) - f(a) = \int_a^x f'(t)dt $$
i.e. (one direction of) the Fundamental theorem of Calculus (FTC_1) does not hold for differentiable a.e. functions.

One standard counterexample is the Cantor function $g$, whose image is the whole interval $[0,1]$ and for which $g'(t)=0$ a.e., meaning that
$$ 1 = g(1) = g(1) - 0 = g(1) - g(0) \neq \int_0^1 g'(t)dt = \int_0^1 0 dt = 0 $$

**My question is**: as far as I know the Cantor function is not weakly differentiable, and I have never seen a counterexample involving a weakly differentiable function (I know that the [Minkowski function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_question-mark_function) provides another counterexample, but I have no idea whether it is weakly differentiable, although again differentiable a.e.). So, is it possible that the FTC_1 always holds for weakly differentiable functions? If not, does anyone know a counterexample?

I am new to Sobolev spaces, but I think that, equivalently, I am asking whether the FTC_1 holds for all functions in $W^{1,1}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Yes, it is true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it’s true. Take a sequence of smooth functions $\phi_k$ supported in $(-1/2k,1/2k)$ with $\int\phi_k = 1$ which converge in the sense of measures to a Dirac measure $\delta_0$ (i.e. $\int \phi_k f \to f(0)$ for continuous $f$). Then define $$\psi_k(x)= \int_{-\infty}^x \phi_k(t-a)-\phi_k(t-x)dt$$

One can check that this function equals $1$ on $(a+1/2k, x-1/2k)$ and is zero outside of $(a-1/2k, x+1/2k)$, so the $\psi_k$ converge a.e. to the indicator function of $(a,x)$, and their derivatives $\psi’_k$ converge in the sense of measures to Dirac measures $\delta_a - \delta_x$.

With this technical construction out of the way (essentially used to smoothly approximate the indicator of $(a,x)$), on one hand by weak differentiability we have

$$\int \psi_k(t) f’(t) dt = -\int \psi’_k(t) f(t) dt \to f(x)-f(a)$$

On the other hand, since $|\psi_kf’|\leq |f’|\in L^1$, and $\psi_k\to\chi_{(a,x)}$ a.e, by the dominated convergence theorem we have

$$\int \psi_k(t) f’(t) dt \to \int_a^x f’(t)dt$$